# Store column in pandas dependent on a list of records under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Be the following pandas DataFrame in Python:

| ID | date | direction | country_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 10:00:01 | IN | USA |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 11:00:01 | IN | UK |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 11:10:01 | OUT | GER |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 12:00:03 | IN | ESP |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 14:32:01 | OUT | USA |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 10:32:01 | OUT | UK |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 11:32:01 | IN | GER |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 14:32:01 | OUT | FRA |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 14:42:01 | OUT | GER |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 08:00:01 | OUT | CAN |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 08:02:01 | IN | FRA |

I need to get the check-in and check-out for each group by ID. They are only recorded if a row with IN appears first and closes the record with a row with OUT as value for direction column (there may be more rows in between with a value of direction IN, as can be seen in the example).

With help of another user (@Timus), I have been able to construct the following table, to which I have also added information on the country of departure and entry. I share the code provided:

```
def connect(df):
    mask = df['direction'].eq('IN')
    ins = list(reversed(df.loc[mask, 'date'].values))
    ins_cams = list(reversed(df.loc[mask, 'country_ID'].values))
    outs = list(reversed(df.loc[~mask, 'date'].values))
    outs_cams = list(reversed(df.loc[~mask, 'country_ID'].values))
    connects = []
    if ins:
        dt_out = ins[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=-1)
    while ins and outs:
        dt_in = None
        while ins:
            dt = ins.pop()
            cam_in = ins_cams.pop()
            if dt > dt_out:
                dt_in = dt
                break
        while dt_in and outs:
            dt_out = outs.pop()
            cam_out = outs_cams.pop()
            if dt_in < dt_out: 
                connects.append([dt_in, dt_out, cam_in, cam_out])
                break

    return pd.DataFrame(connects, columns=['entry_date', 'exit_date', 'start_country', 'end_country'])

result = (df.sort_values(['ID','date']).groupby('ID').apply(connect).droplevel(1, axis=0).reset_index())
```

The result is as follows:

| ID | entry_date | exit_date | start_country | end_country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 10:00:01 | 2022-01-03 11:10:01 | USA | GER |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 12:00:03 | 2022-01-03 14:32:01 | ESP | USA |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 11:32:01 | 2022-01-04 14:32:01 | GER | FRA |

I would also like to add a `list_countries` column, which would contain (in order), the complete list of countries that have been detected between the specific IN and OUT record, i.e:

| ID | entry_date | exit_date | start_country | end_country | list_countries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 10:00:01 | 2022-01-03 11:10:01 | USA | GER | ['USA', 'UK', 'GER'] |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 12:00:03 | 2022-01-03 14:32:01 | ESP | USA | ['ESP', 'USA'] |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 11:32:01 | 2022-01-04 14:32:01 | GER | FRA | ['GER','FRA'] |

I don't mind if you can get the same result using a different code than the one provided. In principle that would not be a problem. I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why dont you have ID2?

Comment: @onyambu I do not understand your question.

Comment: in your output, yu have ID0, ID1 but no ID2

Comment: @onyambu Because the code does not work for records starting with OUT. But that is how it should work. In principle the functionality is already done, but I want to add the list above for each row.

Comment: But ID1 starts with OUT then IN?

Comment: @onyambu '''They are only recorded if a row with IN appears first and closes the record with a row with OUT as value for direction column (there may be more rows in between with a value of direction IN, as can be seen in the example).'''  Considering that an ```entry_date``` is registered by direction = IN and an ```exit_date``` by direction = OUT.

Comment: I understand your statement. But ID1 starts with OUT, and it seems that this row was dropped. Then ID2 starts with OUT, then the row should be dropped. are we also droping the second row because it does not have the OUT to finish?

Comment: @onyambu Indeed, it considers that an ```entry_date``` is registered by direction = IN and an ```exit_date``` by direction = OUT.  Although there may be more rows in between with a value of direction IN, as can be seen in the example. If there is an IN record but no OUT record, we would not be able to complete the row of the new DataFrame, so it is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cutoff(x):
    if x.size == 1:  return False
    elif x.size == 2: return x.head(1).eq('IN') & x.tail(1).eq('OUT')
    else: return (x == 'IN').cummax() & (x=='OUT')[::-1].cummax()
        

df1 = df[df.groupby('ID')['direction'].transform(cutoff)].reset_index(drop = True)                             
df1['grp'] = (df1.direction != df1.direction.shift().bfill()).cumsum()           
df1['grp1'] = df1['grp'] // 2

df2 = (df1.groupby(['grp', 'ID', 'direction', 'grp1']).
       agg({'date':lambda x:x.head(1), 'country_ID':list}).droplevel('grp').unstack(1))  
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(' '.join)

df2['list_country'] = (df2[['country_ID IN', 'country_ID OUT']].
                apply(lambda x: sum(x, []) ,axis = 1))    
a= (df2[['country_ID IN','country_ID OUT']].applymap(lambda x:x[0]))
df2[['country_ID IN', 'country_ID OUT']]  = a

df2.droplevel('grp1')
 
                date IN             date OUT  ... country_ID OUT    list_country
ID                                            ...                               
0   2022-01-03 10:00:01  2022-01-03 11:10:01  ...            GER  [USA, UK, GER]
0   2022-01-03 12:00:03  2022-01-03 14:32:01  ...            USA      [ESP, USA]
1   2022-01-04 11:32:01  2022-01-04 14:32:01  ...            FRA      [GER, FRA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, however, there is an error when adding the country_ID values to the list (list_countries). If at the end of a record there are two rows with an OUT address value in a row, both are added to the list.

Comment: I have added one more record with ```ID = 1, date = 2022-01-04 14:42:01 country_ID = GER``` and ```direction = OUT``` to my DataFrame example. With the code you have provided, the result for list_country, would be ```[GER, FRA, GER]``` and not ```[GER, FRA]``` as it should be.

Comment: Each row ```list_countries``` contains the ```country_ID``` values from the first ```date IN``` in the record to the first ```date OUT``` found.